# Funções e procedimentos em Portugol

Tags: algoritmo, lógica, portugol, portugol-studio

Sobre funções e procedimentos, estou com uma baita duvida neste assunto.

Sei que uma função sempre retornará dados e que procedimento não têm retorno, mas toda função tem que preencher todos os parâmetros? Gostaria de saber porque meu código não esta dando certo, a soma dos números sempre dá zero.

Qual o problema?

```
programa
{
    funcao inicio(){
        inteiro resultado = 0, n1=0, n2=0
        escreve()
        
        escreva(somar(n1,n2))
    }

    funcao escreve(){
        inteiro n1, n2
        escreva("Digite n1 ")
        leia(n1)
        escreva("Digite n2 ")
        leia(n2)    
    }

    funcao inteiro somar(inteiro a, inteiro b){
        retorne a + b
    }
}
```

Comment: Bom, sua função `escreve` é do tipo lê e esquece. Na função você declara duas variáveis: `n1` e `n2`, com escopo restrito à função, a seguir você lê valores para cada uma destas variáveis, mas aí encerra a função, ou seja os valores lidos são perdidos. Note que em sua função `inicio` você declara as variáveis `n1` e `n2` com valor inicial 0 e portanto a chamada da função `somar(n1,n2)` retornará 0, independente do que foi lido em `escreve`. Estude sobre escopo de variáveis.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pelo o que entendi do seu código, está faltando uma variável para retornar a resposta da soma.

programa
{

```
  variavel 
     int n1, n2, resp


  escreva 
   ("Digite n1: ")
  leia n1
  escreva 
    ("Digite n2:  ")
   leia n2

   resp = (n1 + n2)

   escreva 
    ("O resultado é igual á:  " , resp)
```

Answer (score -1):

Observando seu código, `n1` e `n2`, na função `escreve`, são variáveis locais e não estão alterando o valor de `n1` e `n2` declaradas na função `inicio`. Ou seja, quando o programa roda, mesmo que você atribua valor para `n1` e `n2` (que é requisitado pela função `escreve`), o valor que está sendo passado como parâmetro da função `soma` é na verdade o `n1` e `n2` da função `inicio`, que não foram alterados e, portanto, continuam valendo zero. Por isso sua soma resulta em zero.

Achei a função `escreve` desnecessária e coloquei o desenvolvimento dela dentro da função `inicio`, conforme o código a seguir. Neste caso, acredito ser necessária a passagem de parâmetros.

```
função somar(inteiro a, inteiro b){
    int res;

    res = a+b;
    retorne res;
}

funcao inicio{
    int resultado = 0, n1=0, n2=0;

    escreva ("Digite n1: ");
    leia (n1);
    escreva("Digite n2: ");
    leia ("%i", &n2);

    escreva("A soma dos numeros é: ", resultado = somar(n1,n2)); 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

eu refiz seu código com algumas pequenas alterações e funcionou... na sua funcao escreve fiz a passagem por referencia, desse modo, os valores de n1 e n2, são substituídos pelos valores de c e d, que serão os valores digitados pelo usuário.

Espero que ajude nos estudos, tb tô começando agr :)

funcao inicio()
{
inteiro n1 = 0, n2 = 0

```
    escreve (n1, n2)
    
    somar(n1, n2)
}

funcao escreve (inteiro &c, inteiro &d){
    escreva ("Digite um número => ")
    leia (c)
    escreva ("\nDigite outro número => ")
    leia (d)
}

funcao somar (inteiro a, inteiro b){

    escreva ("\nA soma de " + a + " + " + b + " = " + (a + b))
}
```

}